# get signature of NumPy array object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, inspect, method-signature

I'm implementing contextual help in an editor for python that I'm creating.

I want to get the methods of classes and those methods' arguments, but I also want the methods of objects.

For a NumPy array, if I do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import inspect
_members = inspect.getmembers(np)
for _member in _members:
    _params = str(inspect.signature(_member[1]))
```

there's no problem with that. But when I do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import inspect
ar = np.array([1,2,3,4])
_members = inspect.getmembers(type(ar))
for _member in _members:
    _params = str(inspect.signature(_member[1]))
```

I get an error when trying to obtain the signature. Each `_member[1]` looks like this:

```
<method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects>
```

My question: Is a way to unwrap the signature? If that is not possible, is there a workaround to obtain the method arguments?

This considering not only a `np.array`. I'd like to get the methods and arguments of any kind of class or object.

Comment: `np.array` is a function (with its own `signature`) that creates an `np.ndarray` object.  The first code block looks at the objects in the `np` module (mostly constants, functions and classes).  The second block looks at the methods of a class (and other class attributes).

Comment: You need to wrap your `signature` line in a `try` block, because not all attributes of a class will be methods (callable).  For example `attribute 'T'` is a property, not a callable.  I'm surprise that your first code block also worked, because `np` has members that aren't callable, such as constants.

Comment: `ipython` does a nice job of providing this kind of help, with tab complete, and `?` (docs) and `??` (code).  You could play with that to see what kinds of signature you can access and for what.

Answer (score 1):

Most but perhaps not all signatures you can get using the `numpydoc` module:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import inspect
>>> import numpydoc
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
# inspect doesn't work
>>> inspect.signature(np.ndarray.transpose)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paul/local/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 3002, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/paul/local/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 2752, in from_callable
    follow_wrapper_chains=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/paul/local/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 2231, in _signature_from_callable
    skip_bound_arg=skip_bound_arg)
  File "/home/paul/local/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 2061, in _signature_from_builtin
    raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <method 'transpose' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects>
>>> 
>>> info = numpydoc.docscrape.FunctionDoc(np.ndarray.transpose)
>>> info['Signature']
'a.transpose(*axes)'
>>> pprint(info['Parameters'])
[('axes',
  'None, tuple of ints, or `n` ints',
  ['',
   '* None or no argument: reverses the order of the axes.',
   '',
   "* tuple of ints: `i` in the `j`-th place in the tuple means `a`'s",
   "  `i`-th axis becomes `a.transpose()`'s `j`-th axis.",
   '',
   '* `n` ints: same as an n-tuple of the same ints (this form is',
   '  intended simply as a "convenience" alternative to the tuple form)'])]
>>> 
>>> info = numpydoc.docscrape.FunctionDoc(np.ndarray.std)
>>> info['Signature']
'a.std(axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False)'
# sometimes info is incomplete
>>> pprint(info['Parameters'])
[]
```

Comment: your answer was very useful i managed to make a wraparound to all numpy objects.

Still have to save other type of builtin objects, im looking into `ipython` as a comment sugested.

If  I manage to work a solution i will post it here.